# EF how to Attach entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have an object Manager, which has property EmailAccount, type EmailAccount:

```
public class Manager 
{
    .....
    public virtual EmailAccount EmailAccount { get; set; }
}

public partial class EmailAccount : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping between these classes:

```
public class ManagerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Manager>
{
    public ManagerMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Manager");
        this.HasKey(dp => dp.Id);
        this.Property(p => p.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);
        this.Property(p => p.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);
        this.Property(p => p.Nickname).HasMaxLength(250);

        this.HasOptional(c => c.EmailAccount)
            .WithRequired(a => a.Manager)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("ManagerId"));
    }
}
```

then in code I get object Manager from context and update it

```
var manager = _managerService.GetManager(user.Id);
manager.FirstName = model.FirstName;
manager.LastName = model.LastName;
manager.Nickname = model.Nickname;
manager.EmailAccount = mapper.Map<EmailAccount>(model.EmailAccount);
```

So, as we can see, EmailAccount is not gotten from context but uses an external object, but with Id (PK) the same as in context!

Then, before save changes, I try to attach this object to context:

```
_db.EmailAccounts.Attach(manager.EmailAccount);
```

but I got an error:

> Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of
>   type 'Infrastructure.Asset.Messages.EmailAccount' have the same
>   primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are
>   unique.

**ADDED**

`_managerService.GetManager(user.Id)` calls the following method:

```
    public Manager GetManager(string aspNetUserId)
    {
        var manager = _db.Managers
            .Include(p => p.EmailAccount)
            .Where(p => p.AspNetUser.Id == aspNetUserId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return manager;
    }
```

Why so, and how do I do it?

Comment: What happens inside `_managerService.GetManager(user.Id)`?

Comment: @GertArnold added

Comment: Yeah, so you already have an `EmailAccount` attached. You should copy the content of `model.EmailAccount` to the attached one instead of attaching the mapped account.

Comment: @GertArnold, My class can have tens on parameters, I don't want copy every field manually. Any way to do it without manual copying?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to attach it in your case. The following line is sufficient:

```
manager.EmailAccount = mapper.Map<EmailAccount>(model.EmailAccount);
```

Although, you are correct by stating that `EmailAccount` isn't bound to the context, the `manager` object is. By assigning the email account, it will be tracked.

If you do need to attach an object to the context, or want to implement some up-sert logic, see this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: then I got an error : "A relationship from the 'Manager_EmailAccount' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Manager_EmailAccount_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.".